# File exists issues

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm attempting to try and debug the following code with the file_exists function. I've ran a var_dump on the avatar directory and it always returns as bool(false). I'm not sure why. I tested the code below and it gets to the file exists but it proves the if statement false everytime. Any thoughts? I have looked and the image is in the directory correctly.

```
$default_avatar = 'default.jpg';
$avatar_directory = base_url() . 'assets/globals/images/avatars/';
if (!is_null($user_data->avatar))
{
    $avatar = $avatar_directory . $user_data->avatar;
    if (file_exists($avatar))
    {
        $user_data->avatar = $avatar_directory . $user_data->avatar;
    }
    else
    {
        $user_data->avatar = $avatar_directory . $default_avatar;
    }
}
else
{
    $user_data->avatar = $default_avatar;
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `base_url()`?

Comment: easiest way would be to echo `$avatar` and check if its correct path according to your foldr structure.

Comment: why are you trying to use a url for a local directory?

Comment: It is not what `base_url()` is for. You need the local path to the files...

Comment: What do you mean @ppeterka?

Comment: Assuming you're sure that base_url() and that path builds the way you think it does - what are the permissions on them?

Comment: I tried $avatar_directory = '../assets/globals/images/avatars/'; and that didn't work either.

Comment: What they mean is, base_url() references the address section of a url - file_exists() is a filesystem function. The former is remote. The latter is local.

Comment: You're looking for a file that should exist on the same machine as php, right? Use `__DIR__`, not base_url() - edited because markdown mangled syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$default_avatar = 'default.jpg';
$avatar_directory = 'assets/globals/images/avatars/';
if (!is_null($user_data->avatar))
{
    $avatar = $avatar_directory . $user_data->avatar;
    if (file_exists(FCPATH . $avatar))
    {
        $user_data->avatar = base_url() . $avatar_directory . $user_data->avatar;
    }
    else
    {
        $user_data->avatar = base_url() . $avatar_directory . $default_avatar;
    }
}
else
{
    $user_data->avatar = $default_avatar;
}
```

Comment: this is a codeigniter constant defined in index.php. so you should add a `codeigniter` tag in this question

Comment: `FCPATH` is The full server path to THIS file. defined as `define('FCPATH', __FILE__);` Reference http://cxzcxz.com/xref/codeigniter-1.7.1/nav.html?_constants/index.html

Comment: @user2576961, this is still a local file, and not a url like you said you were wanting on my answer

Answer (score 1):

from the name `base_url` seems like a function that will get a url like `http://www.mysite.com`, which will not work for doing local directory functions.

you need something like [`getcwd`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php), or a full path

getcwd will get the current working directory (the directory where the initial script was executed from):

```
//If say script.php was exectued from /home/mysite/www
$avatar_directory = getcwd() . '/assets/globals/images/avatars/';

//$avatar_directory would be
/home/mysite/www/assets/globals/images/avatars/
```

Comment: This isn't for a local directory though this is a live url.

Comment: [file_exists](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) is for looking to see if a local file exists not if a url is readable.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you meant base_url() to point to the root of your project -

```
   $file = __DIR__ . "/path/to/file.ext";

   if (file_exists($file)) {

       //...

   }
```

Or some variation thereof. This also works:

```
   __DIR__ . "/.."
```

- it resolves to the parent directory of `__DIR__`.

see PHP's magic constants:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

If you are looking for a remote resource - a file not located on your local filesystem - you have to change your php.ini to permit that. And it's probably not a good idea, this is not usually considered safe or secure. At all.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php

And note:

```
"This function returns FALSE for files inaccessible due to safe mode restrictions. However these files still can be included if they are located in safe_mode_include_dir."
```

-- from http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

-- edited to add relevant information based on a comment from OP.

Answer (score 1):

Well this works both CLI and via Apache etc...:

```
$avatar_directory = substr(str_replace(pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME), '', __FILE__), 0, -1) . '/assets/globals/images/avatars/'
```

The did returned is the one that the php file itself is in, not the root.